# SQL: Selecting/Ignoring records on the basis of tables in an array

Tags: mysql, sql

Given the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE Test
    (`id` int, `TestName` varchar(7), `description` varchar(55));

INSERT INTO Test
    (`id`, `TestName`, `description`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Test1', 'Td1'),(2, 'Test2', 'Td2'),(3, 'Test3', 'Td2');

CREATE TABLE Forcedata
    (`id` int, `ForceData` varchar(7), `description` varchar(55));

INSERT INTO Forcedata
    (`id`, `ForceData`, `description`)
VALUES
    (1, 'F1', 'Fd1'), (2, 'F2', 'Fd2'), (3, 'F3', 'Fd3');

CREATE TABLE Temp
    (`id` int, `TempName` varchar(7), `description` varchar(55));

INSERT INTO Temp
    (`id`, `TempName`, `description`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Tm1', 'Tmd1'),(2, 'Tm2', 'Tmd2');

    CREATE TABLE Sensor
    (`id` int, `SensorName` varchar(7), `description` varchar(55));

INSERT INTO Sensor
    (`id`, `SensorName`, `description`)
VALUES
    (1, 'S1', 'Sd1'),(2, 'S2', 'Sd2');
```

I want to write a select statement that gets the value from the tables mentioned in one array and this data should not be in any table of the other array. I want to do something like this:

```
DECLARE @ListToCheck VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @ListToCheck = 'Test' + ', ' + 'Forcedata';

DECLARE @TablesToavoid VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @TableToAvoid = 'Temp' + ', ' + 'Sensor';


SELECT id FROM
tables in ('+@ListToCheck+')'
And WHERE id should NOT be IN ('+@TablesToAvoid+')'
```

SO for the above schema only record with id:3 should be selected. thanks in advance :)

Comment: Can I know why 2 Negative Votes??

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

MySQL:

```
   SELECT t.id
    FROM (
        SELECT ID
        FROM Test

        UNION

        SELECT ID
        FROM Forcedata
        ) T
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT ID
        FROM TEMP

        UNION

        SELECT ID
        FROM Sensor
        ) T1 ON T.id = T1.id
    WHERE t1.id IS NULL
```

SQL Server:

```
SELECT ID
FROM Test

UNION

SELECT ID
FROM Forcedata

EXCEPT

(
    SELECT ID
    FROM TEMP

    UNION

    SELECT ID
    FROM Sensor
    )
```

Comment: I know this is how we can do this. The question is that how we can do it using arrays. But thanks anyways